# weird positioning using jquery position()

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, firefox

I'm trying to auto-center an ul list with javascript upon load of the page. It works on all the browsers, however on firefox it works every other time, it's really 50/50 and it's driving me crazy, 
I've setup a jsfiddle in order to show you this behaviour.

I'm pretty sure I've done something wrong, but I can't nail it.

fiddle: http://fiddle.jshell.net/qbv05ph9/5/

this is the actual result, try with firefox, if you refresh the page 50% of times it won't work.

http://fiddle.jshell.net/qbv05ph9/5/show/light/

what's even crazier is that if you ctrl + shift + r or cmd + shift + r it will work 100% of times.

when it gets it wrong console writes:

```
    0 "487.3999938964844 544.5 57.5"
```

while when it's correct:

```
    286 "773.4000244140625 544.5 57.5"
```

for some weird reason when there's the jsfiddle frameset around it works, if it forces you to use the frameset here's the source html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title> - jsFiddle demo</title>

  <script type='text/javascript' src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.js'></script>




  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https:/css/result-light.css">

  <style type='text/css'>
    .list-inline {
margin-left: 0!important;
}
.carousel ul {
white-space: nowrap;
overflow-x: auto;
}
  </style>



<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[
$(window).load(function(){

$(document).ready(function() {

      console.log(Math.round($('#pic_236810').position().left  - ($('#pics').width()/2) + $('#pic_236810').width()/2 ), $('#pic_236810').position().left +" "+ $('#pics').width()/2 + " "+ $('#pic_236810').width()/2 );

    $('#pics').animate({ scrollLeft: Math.round($('#pic_236810').position().left  - ($('#pics').width()/2) + $('#pic_236810').width()/2 ) }, 0);
  })

});//]]>

</script>


</head>
<body>
  <div class="carousel clear">

          <ul class="list-inline" id="pics">
              <li id="pic_236795">
              <div class="thumbdiv media  pics_non_  ">
              <a href="236795"><img alt="" src="http://i.imgur.com/Fp2Vjfi.jpg?1" class="img-responsive
                 thumb">
                </a>
              </div>
            </li>
                      <li id="pic_236809">
              <div class="thumbdiv media  pics_non_  ">
              <a href="236809"><img alt="" src="http://i.imgur.com/Fp2Vjfi.jpg?1" class="img-responsive
                 thumb">
                </a>
              </div>
            </li>
                      <li id="pic_236808">
              <div class="thumbdiv media  pics_non_  ">
              <a href="236808"><img alt="" src="http://i.imgur.com/Fp2Vjfi.jpg?1" class="img-responsive
                 thumb">
                </a>
              </div>
            </li>
                      <li id="pic_236807">
              <div class="thumbdiv media  pics_non_  ">
              <a href="236807"><img alt="" src="http://i.imgur.com/Fp2Vjfi.jpg?1" class="img-responsive
                 thumb">
                </a>
              </div>
            </li>
                      <li id="pic_236806">
              <div class="thumbdiv media  pics_non_  ">
              <a href="236806"><img alt="" src="http://i.imgur.com/Fp2Vjfi.jpg?1" class="img-responsive
                 thumb">
                </a>
              </div>
            </li>
                      <li id="pic_236803">
              <div class="thumbdiv media  pics_non_  ">
              <a href="236803"><img alt="" src="http://i.imgur.com/Fp2Vjfi.jpg?1" class="img-responsive
                 thumb">
                </a>
              </div>
            </li>
                      <li id="pic_236810">
              <div class="thumbdiv media  pics_non_  ">
              <a href="236810"><img alt="" src="http://i.imgur.com/Fp2Vjfi.jpg?1" class="img-responsive
                 thumb">
                </a>
              </div>
            </li>
                      <li id="pic_236805">
              <div class="thumbdiv media  pics_  ">
              <a href="236805"><img alt="" src="http://i.imgur.com/Fp2Vjfi.jpg?1" class="img-responsive
                selected_thumb thumb">
                </a>
              </div>
            </li>
                      <li id="pic_236804">
              <div class="thumbdiv media  pics_  ">
              <a href="236804"><img alt="" src="http://i.imgur.com/Fp2Vjfi.jpg?1" class="img-responsive
                 thumb">
                </a>
              </div>
            </li>
                      <li id="pic_236802">
              <div class="thumbdiv media  pics_  ">
              <a href="236802"><img alt="" src="http://i.imgur.com/Fp2Vjfi.jpg?1" class="img-responsive
                 thumb">
                </a>
              </div>
            </li>
                      <li id="pic_236801">
              <div class="thumbdiv media  pics_  ">
              <a href="236801"><img alt="" src="http://i.imgur.com/Fp2Vjfi.jpg?1" class="img-responsive
                 thumb">
                </a>
              </div>
            </li>
                      <li id="pic_236800">
              <div class="thumbdiv media  pics_  ">
              <a href="236800"><img alt="" src="http://i.imgur.com/Fp2Vjfi.jpg?1" class="img-responsive
                 thumb">
                </a>
              </div>
            </li>
                      <li id="pic_236799">
              <div class="thumbdiv media  pics_  ">
              <a href="236799"><img alt="" src="http://i.imgur.com/Fp2Vjfi.jpg?1" class="img-responsive
                 thumb">
                </a>
              </div>
            </li>
                      <li id="pic_236798">
              <div class="thumbdiv media  pics_  ">
              <a href="236798"><img alt="" src="http://i.imgur.com/Fp2Vjfi.jpg?1" class="img-responsive
                 thumb">
                </a>
              </div>
            </li>
                      <li id="pic_236797">
              <div class="thumbdiv media  pics_  ">
              <a href="236797"><img alt="" src="http://i.imgur.com/Fp2Vjfi.jpg?1" class="img-responsive
                 thumb">
                </a>
              </div>
            </li>
                      <li id="pic_236796">
              <div class="thumbdiv media  pics_  ">
              <a href="236796"><img alt="" src="http://i.imgur.com/Fp2Vjfi.jpg?1" class="img-responsive
                 thumb">
                </a>
              </div>
            </li>

          </ul>
        </div>

</body>


</html>
```

Comment: Images aren't neccessarely loaded on DOM ready, so the widht and height isn't known at that time

Comment: > $(window).load(function() {

Comment: Oh, you actually wrapped the DOM ready in window.onload

Comment: But you didn't in the fiddle ?

Comment: that's jsfiddle doing it for you, of course on actual code I've tried with both methods, but same difference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so, after some head bashing I found a solution that it's working just fine for me, here it goes:

```
        var p = document.getElementById("pic_"+_opts.center_pic);
        var left = p.offsetLeft ;
        var offset = (($('#pics').width()/2) - $('#pic_'+_opts.center_pic).width()/2 );
        $('#pics').animate({ scrollLeft: Math.round(left - offset) }, 0);
```

good ol' js